# How do i generate new id?

Tags: vb.net

I am having problem to this code when i press New button its not generating incremented number from my database so i am wondering where is the wrong in the code this is the code i am using.

```
Dim getcode As String = "0"
cmd = New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "select top (1) * from TBL_EMPLOYEE order by EmployeeID desc"
Try
    cn.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
    If (reader.HasRows = True) Then
        While reader.Read
            getcode = (reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EmployeeID")))
        End While
    End If
    cn.Close()
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
If (getcode = "0") Then
    Me.txtEMPID.Text = "EMPID-000001"
ElseIf (getcode <> "0") Then
    Dim totalcodewithoutlabel As String = getcode.Count - 4
    Dim oldnum As String = getcode.Substring(getcode.Length - totalcodewithoutlabel)
    Me.txtEMPID.Text = "EMPID-" + Format(oldnum + 1, "000000").ToString
End If
```

Comment: Do not: `Catch ex As Exception End Try` You swallow exceptions. Also, in general this is a database task. A client should not fiddle around with creating ID's. Otherwise it's possible that somewhere else the same ID is created at the same time. It's a race condition.

Comment: Yes, I think @TimSchmelter is right. What if the `User1` and `User2` click the `new button` in same time?

Comment: @RichardBaluyut: or this code is executed in a loop that uses threads or the admin is inserting, updating or deleting records directly in the DB or ....

Comment: its when you click the button it will generate new id (ex. there's an existing id called EMPID-000001 , if you pressed New with these code it must be generate code EMPID-000002.)

Comment: But the question Tim is raising (assuming that this isn't intended to be a *single user system*) is, what happens when two people hit this button at the *same time*?

Comment: there's only single user in my system creating.

Comment: @InggoKalatutay: Why you need to store the prefix `EMPID` into each and every record of this table? That's unnecessary and causes this question and probably other issues as well(performance and the race condition). Just use an `IDENTITY` int-column, let the value automatically increment and format it at the client where you want to show it: `Dim empId = id.ToString().PadLeft(5, "0"c)  txtEMPID.Text = $"EMPID-{empId}"`

Comment: I think, and just a suggestion, just random the numbers (For eg. `EMPID-325362` if the user click the new button just random it again `EMPID-456124`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter If i use identity in sql server i will be having a problem that if i deleted a specific row and restore the deleted row the old id will get new id again because its auto incremented (or probably it will error).

Comment: @InggoKalatutay: if you need that restore feature write another stored-procedure that takes the old values as parameter and uses this: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TBL_EMPLOYEE ON;` at the beginning and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TBL_EMPLOYEE OFF;` at the end. You can call these stored-procedures also from VB.NET with ADO.NET and pass the parameters.

Comment: I think, `reader.GetOrdinal("EmployeeID")` returns you the ordinal in the reader-array. You can try `reader.GetInt32("EmployeeID")`

Comment: Another thing: this query is the same as yours: `select max(EmployeeID) from TBL_EMPLOYEE`

Comment: @TimSchmelter how do i code that? it should be like this?
cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT TBL_EMPLOYEE ON "